# Consuming service with SSO authentication in java?

Tags: java, rest, saml

I'm developing a web service that consumes another one. To authenticate with this other service, I have to use the SAML V2 protocol. How to programmatically consume this service in Java ?

My code without SSO:

```
HttpClient client = builder.build();

URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder();
uriBuilder.setScheme(test.getScheme());
uriBuilder.setHost(test.getHost());
uriBuilder.setPort(test.getPort());
uriBuilder.setPath("Path");
uriBuilder.addParameter("id","theID");
uriBuilder.addParameter("param", "param");
try {
  HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(uriBuilder.build());
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
  return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
} catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build a SAML response that meets the requirements of the target service and include it in the call. Your best option is [OpenSAML](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OS30/Home) or another "product" such as [CXF](https://github.com/apache/cxf) that builds on top of it. See [How to create a valid SAML 2.0 Assertion with OpenSAML library in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579742/how-to-create-a-valid-saml-2-0-assertion-with-opensaml-library-in-java) for an OpenSAML example; CXF ships with good docs and examples.